# The free cocompletion of a complete locally small category is complete

Tags: reference-request, category-theory

$\DeclareMathOperator{\colim}{colim}\newcommand{\cat}{\mathbf}\DeclareMathOperator{\Nat}{Nat}$I'm looking for a reference that talks about the free cocompletion $\hat{\cat C}$ of a (large) locally small category $\cat C$ or sanity check of my own attempt [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1796077/400).

Presuming the above is fine, I'm also looking for a reference or sanity check that the free cocompletion of a (large) complete locally small category is itself complete. The two statements I have in mind are these.

1. Let $I$ be a small discrete category. Then $\hat{\cat C}$ has $I$-products if $\cat C$ has $I$-products.
2. If $\mathbf C$ has pullbacks (resp. equalizers), then $\hat{\mathbf C}$ has pullbacks (resp. equalizers).

*Attempt at elementary proof of 1.* Suppose that $J\xrightarrow{p}I$ is a small discrete family of small categories, and $p^{-1}(i)\xrightarrow{F_i}\cat C$ a family of small diagrams in $\cat C$. Define $K$ to be the category of sections of $f$, i.e. its objects are sequences of elements $j_i\in p^{-1}(i)$ and its morphisms are families of morphisms $j_i\to j'_i\in p^{-1}(i)$. Define a diagram $K\xrightarrow{F}\mathbf C$ by $F((j_i))=\prod_i F_i(j_i)\in\cat C$ and its obvious extension to morphismss. Then I claim $\colim_{(j_i)\in K} F((j_i))=\lim_i\colim_{j_i\in p^{-1}(i)} F_i(j_i)$.

Indeed by the Yoneda lemma, $$\Nat(X,\colim_{(j_i)\in K}F((j_i)))=\colim_{(j_i)}\prod_i\Nat(X,F_i(j_i))$$ and I claim this latter equals $$\prod_i\colim_{j_i\in p^{-1}(i)}\Nat(X,F_i(j_i))=\prod_i\Nat(X,F_i)$$
An elementary argument is this.
An element of the first set is given by an element $(j_i)\in K$ and an $I$-indexed family of morphism $X\to F_i(j_i)$ subject to the equivalence  that two such families are equivalent if there exists an $I$-indexed family of morphisms $j_i\to j'_i$ so that each $X\to F_i(j_i)$ factors as $X\to F_i(j_i)\to F_i(j'_i)$.

An element of the second set is also given by an $I$-indexed family of morphisms $X\to F_i(j_i)$ but subject to an a priori coarser equivalence relation: two such families are equivalent if for each $i\in I$ there exists either $j_i\to j'_i$ or $j'_i\to j_i$ so that $X\to F_i(j_i)$ factors through $F_i(j_i)\to F_i(j'_i)$ or $X\to F_i(j'_i)$ factors through $F_i(j'_i)\to F_i(j_i)$.

But the second relation is actually the same as the first. Indeed, given two equivalent families $X\to F_i(j_i)$ and $X\to F_i(j'_i)$ in the second relation, we may partition $I=I_1\sqcup I_2$ with $I_1=\{i\in I:X\to F_i(j_i)$ factors through $F_i(j_i)\to F_i(j'_i)\}$ and $I_2=\{i\in I:X\to F_i(j'_i)$ factors through $F_i(j'_i)\to F_i(j_i)\}$.
Then we can build a new family $k_i=\begin{cases}j_i&i\in I_1\\j'_i&i\in I_2\end{cases}$ and obtain a new family $X\to F_i(k_i)$. Then we have that each $X\to F_i(k_i)$ factors through $F_i(k_i)\to F_i(j_i)$ and through $F_i(k_i)\to F_i(j'_i)$. Thus, the family $X\to F_i(k_i)$ is equivalent in the first relation to $X\to F_i(j_i)$ and $X\to F_i(j'_i)$.

Comment: This is one reference https://ncatlab.org/toddtrimble/published/Small+cocompletions but I am looking for something at the level of exercises in using the Yoneda lemma in a first course on category theory.

Comment: It's neither obvious nor easy, I think. A much more general result (for finite limits) can be found in e.g. [Shulman, _Exact completions and small sheaves_]. For a sense of the difficulty of proving such a result using "elementary" methods, you might trace the proof of Theorem 1.4.16 in [my thesis](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~zll22/thesis.pdf).

Comment: To be clear, you mean that the second statement is neither obvious nor easy, or is my sketch of proof of the first statement wrong?

Comment: I don't think it is so easy to construct products either.

Comment: See also Day & Lack's [_Limits of small functors_](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2324597). Corollary 3.9 states that the free cocompletion of a complete category is complete.

Comment: @AlexanderCampbell thanks that looks very nice; an arxiv link is http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0610439v1.pdf

Comment: @ZhenLin I filled in the details of the elementary proof for products, did I screw up? I'm aghast the problem in your thesis hadn't been resolved way earlier, but I'm very glad you've worked it out, I think it's an important matter to settle.